# Scala convert tuple to JSON using Jerkson

Tags: json, scala

Code snippet in `REPL`

```
scala> import com.codahale.jerkson.Json._
scala> val t = (1, 3.14, "Fred")
scala> generate(t)
res5: String = {"_1":1,"_2":3.14,"_3":"Fred"}
```

In the output, I want to assign labels to attributes instead of `_1`, `_2`, `_3`. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `case class` instead of a tuple:

```
case class Named(myInt: Int, thisDouble: Double, desc: String)
generate(Named(1, 3.14, "Fred"))
```

Gives:

```
{"myInt": 1.0,"thisDouble":3.14,"desc":"Fred"}
```

Comment: That works great! But what if I need to use a tuple, is there a simple solution?